# Using Redux and React Hooks, Flatlist will not re-render nor will the individual components inside of it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native, React Hooks, Redux and Function components. I am using useSelector to get a large array from my state from Redux and I iterate through it using a Flatlist. In my Flatlist I render multiple child components, including children of my child. I pasted the main child at the bottom of this post. When I am on a separate screen and the FlatList is inactive and a property changes inside of an object in my array `trackingBoardList`, I expect that Flatlist will rerender when I come back to the screen, but it doesn't. Furthermore, even if I try to memoize the child component `AvatarListItem` using `React.memo()`, the child by itself also will also not re-render. I cannot get the full list to re-render, nor can I get the children by themselves to re-render. Is Flatlist incompatible with React Hooks and arrays, with nested objects? In my reducer I am indeed returning that array immutably when it changes, and I'm doing that using Immer `draft`.

I get my state with useSelector. It's a large array with lots of deep nested objects:

```js
  const trackingBoardList = useSelector((state: iAppState) => {
    return state.trackingBoardAndSchedule.trackingBoardList;
  });
```

My Flatlist looks like this:

```js
    <FlatList
            data={trackingBoardList}
            extraData={trackingBoardList}
            keyExtractor={() => uuid()}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                  <AvatarListItem
                    patientID={item.patient.id}
                    patientFirstName={item.patient.name_first}
                    patientLastName={item.patient.name_last}
                    patientMiddleName={item.patient.name_middle}
                    patientSex={item.patient.gender}
                    patientAge={calculateAge(item.patient.birth_dttm)}
                    visitReason={item.reason_for_visit}
                    time={item.created_dttm}
                    inProgress={false}
                    patientAvatarURI={item.patient.profile_image_name}
                    status={item.evisit_status}
                  />
              );
            }}
          />
```

My child component looks like this:

```js
const AvatarListItem = (props: iAvatarListItem) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ListItemContainer {...props}>
        <Avatar
          avatarSize={42}
          avatarType='patient'
          avatarUserID={props.patientID}
          avatarURI={props.patientAvatarURI}
        />
        <NameAgeColumn>
          <ColumnTitle>
            {props.patientFirstName}
            {props.patientMiddleName ? ` ${props.patientMiddleName}` : ''}
            {` ${props.patientLastName}`}
          </ColumnTitle>
          <ColumnSmallText>
            {props.patientSex === 'M' ? 'Male, ' : ''}
            {props.patientSex === 'F' ? 'Female, ' : ''}
            {props.patientAge} Years
          </ColumnSmallText>
        </NameAgeColumn>
        <ReasonColumn>
          <ColumnTitle>Reason</ColumnTitle>
          <ColumnSmallText>{props.visitReason}</ColumnSmallText>
        </ReasonColumn>
        <LongBadge>
          <LongBadgeText>{props.status}</LongBadgeText>
        </LongBadge>
      </ListItemContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default AvatarListItem;
```

Comment: Where are you actually using trackingBoardList inside of ```Flatlist?```  Also how/where are you dispatching actions that change the state?

Comment: Hi @RutherfordWonkington I found my bug down below but to answer your question, when an array is provided as `data` to `Flatlist` it iterates over that data. Therefore each object in `trackingBoardList` is `item` for each iteration same as a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own problem, I discovered the bug immediately after I posted this. It was a mutability issue. I was assured that my state was immutable using ImmerJS however instead of using my `draft` state Immer was somehow automajically using my baseState, which worked almost everywhere throughout the app but finally caused an issue on this particular screen. If you are having a very strange re-rendering issue where a component just refuses to re-render no matter what you do, I highly recommend focusing on your reducer and trying a few different ways of returning your state.